# managing a dynamic list of event subscriptions in C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, events, object, dynamic

If I have a bunch of objects of same class that gets dynamically created or destroyed and I want to subscribe to an event in each object how would I go about managing those subscriptions?  Is there a class in .NET where it could hold a list of event subscriptions?  The scenario would be a weather stations with live data displayed on a map.  For each weather station that's visible on the map I would subscribe to a sensor.  However when that station is no longer visible I would unsubscribe to the event.  Or would the better solution be to manage the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know what language you're using. In VB.NET there's a great thing called `AddHandler` to wire up any object's event to a procedure.

Let's say you have this procedure when you acquire an object you want to keep track of (`EventClass` is some class that raises the `StuffHappened` event that gives no other parameters):

```
Sub AddEntity(Entity As EventClass)
    ' do the normal stuff, add to list maybe
    AddHandler Entity.StuffHappened, Sub() Happenings(Entity)
End Sub
```

The `Sub() Happenings(Entity)` is a lambda, a mini-subroutine that, in this case, closes over the `Entity` object. So, when the class raises the event, your `Happenings` sub is called with the raiser passed as an argument. If your event gives some parameters, include them in the parentheses in `Sub()` and pass them appropriately to your handler.

Comment: I'm doing this in c#,  what you're describing sounds like a method that registers my objects event to some event handler, in my case to update the image.  How would i handle registered events when the object is no longer needed?  Would i just unsubscribe to that objects event?